# exportfs: Warning: /home/user/share does not support NFS export

Tags: nfs, export, ext4

'exportfs -r' returns me this error when I'm trying to export /home/user/share (ext4):

> exportfs: Warning: /home/user/share does not support NFS export.

/etc/exports:

> /home/user/share 192.168.1.3 (rw,no_subtree_check)

The system is Ubuntu 10.04 with nfs-kernel-server package. Any ideas why this is happening? Is it because of ext4?

Comment: This may be a related bug.  http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=602956 Have you considered using a user-space NFS server?

Comment: Same problem on ubuntu 11.04.
Can't export dir in encrypted home dir, but if i create a new dir e.g. /exports it works fine with nfs.

Answer (score 31):

nfs-kernel-server cannot work with a FUSE folder like an encrypted **ecryptfs** home directory.

Comment: Can you explain why that is so? Are there other nfs server packages that would work with FUSE?

Comment: An user-space NFS server like UNFS3 may works http://unfs3.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've tried to find a NFS4 version of that, with no success. Anyway, thanks for the info.

Comment: you should accept this reply as the anwser to your question.

Comment: eCryptfs doesn't use FUSE, but you can't export directories inside eCryptfs with NFS anyway.

Comment: 11 years on and this one-liner "answer" has 30 up-votes although is not providing any specific solution. _nfs-kernel-server cannot work with a FUSE folder like an encrypted ecryptfs home directory_ states a **problem**, not a **solution**.

Comment: @rags2riches-prog If it's unsupported, then it's a correct answer. On SF the OP must be notified if they try to do a unsupported task. The OP clearly waited to see if an update or bugfix make the problem go away by not marking this answer.

Answer (score 4):

After some time I think I have solution. Due to NFS doesn't work under encrypted directory and this is probably only your home folder, you must move your directory to unencrypted space. In my case I've move vangrat project dir from /home/me/vagrant/project > /var/www/vagrant/porject. And boom, is working!

Also you can try play around and turn off encryption in your home folder but this is up to you.

Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem due to a space in the path. Renaming the folder to remove all spaces resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was I was trying to use NFS with an external disk that was formatted with `exfat`.

Reformatting the disk to `ext4` worked.

Comment: Argh. Just got bitten by the same problem. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue with 10.10.  I believe it has something to do with having your export file system encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to install nfs server inside LXD container you will get this error.
to avoid that you need to launch lxd container with additional options like that:

```
# lxc launch ubuntu:22.04  nfs-02   -c security.privileged=true -c raw.apparmor="mount fstype=rpc_pipefs, mount fstype=nfsd,"
```

initially the solution was found [here](https://github.com/HSBawa/nfs-server-on-linux-container)